# Group By all activities into the same row

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have a table similar as follows. There is a number of clicks per activity per customer:

```
customer     activity       total
tim           view           10
tim           view           10
anna          view           20
anna          buy            10
```

My desired output is as the table below:

```
customer     view_count    view      buy_count      buy 
tim              2          20           0           0
anna             1          20           1          10
```

However, this is the returned table that I have at the moment:

```
customer    view_count      view          buy_count         buy 
tim             2            20               0              0
anna            1            20               0              0
anna            0            0                1              10
```

It does not group all the activity of anna into 1 same row. Here is the query that I tried

```
SELECT customer,
       COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'view' THEN customer END), 0) AS view_count,
       COALESCE((CASE WHEN activity = 'view' THEN SUM(total) END), 0) AS view, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'buy' THEN customer END), 0) AS buy_count,
       COALESCE((CASE WHEN activity = 'buy' THEN SUM(total) END), 0) AS buy, 
FROM table 
GROUP BY customer, activity
```

I assume the reason why it is in multiple rows is because of the last row `GROUP BY customer, activity` when I grouped by for activity. However, if I remove it the query returned the error so I had to include it.

Any suggestions that you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close.  The idea is:

```
SELECT customer,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'view' THEN customer END) AS view_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN activity = 'view' THEN total ELSE 0 END)AS view, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'buy' THEN customer END) AS buy_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN activity = 'buy' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS buy
FROM table 
GROUP BY customer ;
```

Note that the `CASE` expression is an argument to the aggregation function.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. You can do:

```
select
  customer,
  sum(case when activity = 'view' then 1 else 0 end) as view_count,
  sum(case when activity = 'view' then total else 0 end) as view,
  sum(case when activity = 'buy' then 1 else 0 end) as buy_count,
  sum(case when activity = 'buy' then total else 0 end) as buy
from t
group by customer
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great suggested solution